# How to move to another position and " animate " a circle in Raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have created a dot as a small circle and wanted to animate to see how it works it moving from the x : 300, y : 390 , r: 5  to 300, 130 . I have searched on the web how to animate a circle and found more about how to animate the RADIUS of it, but is not what I need. I want the same radius dot to move from one point to the otherone. I found some things about along the path / " .animateAlong()" . Is this what i need ? Which are the attribute this " along the path are expecting ?

I want the circle to move animate once the code runs. Don't want to change the position by mouse listening.

Would appreciate some clarity about it , if possible a simple code example for me to see how does it works.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the respective attribute you want to animate, in this case cx & cy (cx, cy is center for circle, rects have x,y).

```
myCircleElement.animate({ cy: 150 }, 2000);
```